# 2D array using strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm stuck on some homework which isn't graded (its meant for practice).

I have to create a function called `find_name` that takes 2 arguments.  The first argument is a 2D array of names (strings), and the second is a character string which is used to find the name in the 2D array, the function must return 1 if found else 0.

When i call the function (which is empty right now), I get this `warning: passing argument 1 of 'find_name' from incompatible pointer type`

Here is the important bits.

**In Main**

```
 char strNameList[][2] = { { "Luca","Daniel"} ,{"Vivan","Desmond"},{"Abdul","Justin"}, {"Nina","Marlene"},{"Donny","Kathlene"} };

char strFindName[] = "\0";
    printf("Please enter a name to look for: ");
    gets(strFindName);
    nSearch = find_name(strNameList, strFindName);
```

**The Function**

```
int find_name(char strNameList[][2], char strLookUp[])
```

I'm new to C (I'm a student), and I'm completely confused about strings (string arrays etc).

Comment: What do you want to declare `char * strNameList[][2]` or `char strNameList[][2]`?

Comment: oops i have char strNameList, not char *strNameList

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming you want a 2D array of char pointers. Your declaration of strNameList is incorrect in *both* locations in your program. You have:

```
char strNameList[][2] = { { "Luca","Daniel"} ,{"Vivan","Desmond"},{"Abdul","Justin"}, {"Nina","Marlene"},{"Donny","Kathlene"} };
```

But `char[][N]` is declaring a 2D array of *`chars`*, not `char*` Therefore you're being warned by the compiler you're assigning a raft of pointer values to items of type `char`

Change *both* your declarations (your variable *and* your function parameter) to:

```
const char *strNameList[][2]
```

which declares an array of unknown length of arrays of two `char*`, which now matches your initialization lists. Also, the `const` is added because (a) I'm assuming you are not planning on modify that name list in your function, and (b) writable string literal declarations assigned to `char*` via initializer is undefined behavior in C, and officially deprecated in C++, so you should not be using it regardless. Likewise, your lookup-name is probably not being modified either, so also declare it `const`.

Result:

```
const char * strNameList[][2] = { 
    {"Luca","Daniel"} ,
    {"Vivan","Desmond"},
    {"Abdul","Justin"}, 
    {"Nina","Marlene"},
    {"Donny","Kathlene"} 
};
```

and in your function:

```
int find_name(const char * strNameList[][2], const char strLookUp[])
```

Last but certainly not least, unless you have a crystal ball your `find_name()` function has no way of knowing with the given information *how many names are in the name list being passed*. I'd rather you see this now rather than wonder what happened later. you need to either (a) terminate the list with a token-value that `find_name()` knows about, or (b) pass the number of names in the list to `find_name()`. To each their own, but I prefer the latter of these:

```
int find_name(const char * strNameList[][2], size_t nNameListSize, const char strLookUp[])
```

and invoke it on your caller side by:

```
find_name(strNameList, sizeof(strNameList)/sizeof(strNameList[0]), strFindName)
```

Comment: +1 for the `const` I missed ... - as `strcpy(strNameList[0][0], "alk");` would crash the app at least if using a recent `gcc`.

Comment: *"writable string literal declarations assigned to char** via initializer is a deprecated feature of C"*. That's not exactly true. It's deprecated in C++ and valid in C. C string literals are not  `const`, but it is undefined behavior to modify them: *"[...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined."* (C11 6.4.5/7, String Literals)

Comment: @netcoder I really need to pick a language and stick with it. Every time I work with one it rubs in the face of the other. I declared a VLA in C++ the other day and stared at it for 10 minutes trying to remember why it wouldn't compile. Thanks, sir, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Passing the array's size around is not necessarily needed is the array is terminated by a stopper element. Please see my answer for this mod.

Comment: @alk That would be option a, "(a) terminate the list with a token-value that find_name() knows about"

Comment: @alk sok. stare at enough SO posts eventually they all blend into giant plate of linguini with marinara. easy to miss stuff. I certainly do, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Do it this way:

```
#define STOPPER_NAMELIST NULL

char * strNameList[][2] = { 
  { "Luca","Daniel"},
  {"Vivan","Desmond"},
  {"Abdul","Justin"}, 
  {"Nina","Marlene"}, 
  {"Donny","Kathlene"} 
  {STOPPER_NAMELIST, STOPPER_NAMELIST}
};

size_t sizeNameList(const char * strNameList[][2])
{
  size_t size = 0;

  while ((strNameList[size][0] != STOPPER_NAMELIST) && 
         (strNameList[size][0] != STOPPER_NAMELIST))
    ++ size;

  return size;
}

int find_name(char * strNameList[][2], char strLookUp[])
{
   size_t size = sizeNameList(strNameList);

   ...
}

...

nSearch = find_name(strNameList, strFindName);
```

This approach uses an open array (`[]`) of `char *` arrays with `2` entries.

---

**Update:**

You could add a stopper element to the array carring the names, then there is no need to pass around the array's size along with array itself, as the size could alway be determined by scanning the array members until the stopper is found.

Comment: I get this now. warning: excess elements in array initializer|
warning: (near initialization for 'strNameList[0]')

Comment: Yeah got it you modified the find_name also , I was looking into older one..+1

Comment: To get *Luca* just do `strNameList[0][0]` and for *Vivan* do `strNameList[1][0]`. @Omkant

Comment: Herp derp i didn't group the elements in pairs indicated by '[][2]'.  Going to build find_name now as all the errors are gone.

Comment: i need to pass 2 arguments to find_name.

Comment: Please see my update on how to get around passing the array's size. @LucaTenuta

Comment: Lets say i want to have the second axis be a none constant count. So for example. char* arr[10][]. Anyway that would work because I can't understand how malloc would create the spaces for each string in those elements and how to even know the count, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Your function `find_name()` is looking for a 2-D array of characters ie:

```
char arr[][2] = { { 'a', 'b'}, ...
```

if you want to make them *strings* you need:

```
char *arr[][2] = { {"John", "Smith"}, ...
```

Then in the function parameter list you need:

```
void find_name(char *something[][2])
{
   printf("first name: %s, second name: %s\n", something[0][0], something[0][1]);
```

And in your `main()` function call it just by:

```
find_name(arr);
```