# How to iterate through a char ** pointer?

Tags: c, loops, pointers

I have the following code

```
struct my_struct {
    const char **enjoy;
};

const char * enjy[] = {
    "Cricket", "movie", "",
    "Ball", "eat", "",
    };

static const struct my_struct my_struct_table[1] = {
    [0] = {
        .enjoy = enjy
        }
};
```

Now I want to use that final structure and want to iterate using that.
How can I iterate using `my_struct_table[0].enjoy`

I want to print all the strings in the `enjy` variable.

Comment: You need to add a way of knowing where the end of the list is

Comment: Danger: I believe the `.enjoy = enjy;` only works in C. In C++ you should use a constructor, or in a simple case like this, [Aggregate Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: Is `[0] = { .enjoy = enjy }` valid in C++? It looks like something mixed with VB.

Comment: Hmmm, it is working fine with me. I am using linux and g++

Comment: @M.M give me an example. So that I can understand it

Comment: @DeanSeo it's only valid in C

Comment: I included c header files.  `#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>`

Comment: Including C headers doesn't make it valid C++. I retagged it C because it *is* C, not C++.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13501579/694576

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let `T` be any type. When working on an array of `T` of varying size, represented as `T*`, you need to specify how the end of such array is represented.

In a simpler case: for a string of characters, i.e. `T = char`, the end of array `char*` is typically represented by a null character `\0`. Thus, you can iterate it as:

```
char* ptr = myString;
for (char c = *ptr; c; c=*++ptr) {
    ...
}
```

You iterate over all characters, until you reach the one that is `\0`, making the expression `c` evaluate to `false`/`0` and break the loop.

An alternative representation for a string is to represent the length of the string as a separate number. This is done, for example, in Pascal strings.

```
int size = myStringSize;
for (int idx=0; idx<size; ++idx) {
    char c = myString[idx];
}
```

---

Either of the approaches can also be used when you have an array of strings (i.e. `T = char*`). Your options are:

- You store a special non-string value in your `enjoy` array set to `NULL` at the end of the array
- Or you store the total size of the `enjoy` array in a separate value.

You can also use *both* options -- this is the case, for example, with arguments given to `int main(int argc, char** argv)`. The `argc` stores the number of string values in the `argv`, *and* `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be `NULL`.

If you use the first option you would then iterate it as:

```
char** ptr = enjoy;
for (char* c = *ptr; c; c=*++ptr) {
    ...
}
```

and if you use the second option:

```
int size = enjoySize;
for (int idx=0; idx<size; ++idx) {
    char* str = enjoy[idx];
}
```

Notice the similarity of these snippets iterating over `char**`, to those used for iterating over a simple `char*`.

Note that a value `NULL` stored in the `enjoy` array is *different* than storing a pointer to an empty string. The latter should not be used as a marker for the end of the array, because it can lead to hard-to-track bugs when a legitimate empty-string value is added to your `enjoy` array.

Comment: I can only access `my_struct_table[0].enjoy` which is char ** . And I know the size. `my_struct_table[0].enjoy[idx] ` does not working

Comment: If you know the size, use the second method. `my_struct_table[0].enjoy[idx]` should be working unless there is something you are not telling us. Maybe write in your question how you attempt to iterate so that we may spot the problem.

Comment: I shared everything, I am getting this error `read.cpp:23:46: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
      char* str = my_struct_table[0].enjoy[idx];
`

Comment: @AQU: Then change `char* str ...` to be `const char* str ...`.